# Java: IOUtils.toByteArray(input) taking too long for some requests causing high TP99.9

Tags: java, arrays, buffer, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm using following code snippet in logging my requests. Most of the I time my requests are serving within 100ms. But, some times its taking too long to read buffer which is causing high TP99.9.

```
final HttpServletRequest rq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
final BufferedReqWrapper brq = new BufferedReqWrapper(rq);
```

And then in BufferedReqWrapper

```
private final BufferingIPStream bis;


public BufferedReqWrapper(final HttpServletRequest req, final Integer maxBytesToBuffer) throws IOException
    {
        super(req);
        bis = new BufferingIPStream(super.getInputStream());
    }
```

In BufferingIPStream

```
public BufferingIPStream(final InputStream delegate) throws IOException
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        buffer = fillBuffer(delegate);
    }
```

and fillbuffer method is

```
private byte[] fillBuffer(final InputStream input) throws IOException
{
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
}
```

This code works fine for most of the requests but taking long time some times which causing high latency more than 1000ms (TP99.9 goes high).

Answer (score 1):

That is expected as `InputStream` read is blocking, meaning that when you call `read` the method will block (waits until data is available). IOUtils.toByteArray would rely on the `read` method of the stream somehow.

Comment: Is there any other way which can make it fast in converting InputStream to Byte array?

Comment: not really no, if the data is not available then there is no way to read it faster.

Comment: Why data would not be there as I capture request and send pass it as parameter ```final HttpServletRequest rq = (HttpServletRequest) request;``` ? When I capture request then we see data in this variable. Is it related to machine capacity or resources?

Comment: The `HttpServletRequest` does not contain the data.  The data comes from a stream that you open using the `HttpServletRequest` object.  The stream reads data from the remote client.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible reasons for this:

1. A client (e.g. browser) could be on a slow machine or a slow network.  `IOUtils.toByteArray` ... or indeed anything ... can only read data from a remote system as fast as the data comes over the network.
2. Some of the requests could be large; i.e. much larger than a typical one.  A larger request will take longer to read into a `byte[]`.
3. You could be seeing GC pauses.  If the GC tuning is well-adapted to your workload, long GC pauses should be rare.  However, it is possible that particular request patterns are causing the GC to pause for long enough that you get long request times.

It is worth noting that reading a large request into a `byte[]` is going to require a number of memory allocations, with the largest one being up to 2 times the size of your request.  Large memory allocations are more likely to lead to (more expensive) old generation collections.  In the worst case, excessively large collections can trigger a "full" garbage collection which (depending on the GC selection and tuning) can lead to significant pauses.

Finally, you shouldn't discount the possibility that the long request times are actually due to something else happening in your webapp ... or another process ... or a another virtual server on the same hypervisor as yours.

I would advise:

- logging request sizes to see if they correlate to slow requests
- logging client IPs and look for a correlation
- turning on GC logging and look for a correlation
- if you have system load graphs (CPU, Disk I/O, Network I/O) look for a correlation

Use your observations to try and figure out what the problem is likely to be.  (Guessing a cause without any evidence is never a good idea ...)